# how to add a datepicker in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic3

As am begginer to ionic, i want to add a datepicker to my input fields in ionic i had tried several methods but no one could support so please any one help me to add a date picker plugin to a ionic 3 input fields

Answer (score 3):

You can use native ionic datepicker (it is using cordova datepicker): https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/

or you can use a ion-datetime as suggested in the comments: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

Comment: ion-input is meant for text type inputs only, such as text, password, email, number, search, tel, and url..https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/. Also https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-2-fixing-date-inputs-for-the-mobile-web/

Comment: didn't know it.. but somehow ion-input with type="date" works for me too.

Comment: that isnt advisible for mobile UI

Answer (score 1):

Don't need any native plugin for **ionic v4** just need to use the html template.

```
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMMM YY, HH:mm a" min="1999" max="2025">
   </ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-native-date-time-picker-using-native-datepicker-plugin-tutorial-by-example/) native **Ionic 4** plugin DatePicker plugin

**Date Picker**

[image]

**Time Picker**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to install Cordova date-picker.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-datepicker
npm install @ionic-native/date-picker
```

then import the datepicker in your component and use it...

```
  import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';

    constructor(private datePicker: DatePicker) { }


    ...


    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
    }).then(
      date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-datepicker
npm install @ionic-native/date-picker

app.module.ts
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';
providers: [
  DatePicker
]

import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';

constructor(private datePicker: DatePicker) { }

this.datePicker.show({
 date: new Date(),
 mode: 'date',
 androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
}).then(
 date => console.log('date: ', date),
 err => console.log('error ', err)
);
```

**THEME_HOLO_DARK:**
[image]

**THEME_HOLO_DARK:**
[image]

**THEME_HOLO_LIGHT:**
[image]

**THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT:**

for Dark theme **THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK**
[image]